# CSS drop down menu hover not working

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a simple dropdown menu and cannot understand why it is not revealing itself on hover. I can hide it so I know I'm targeting the right code, but it does nothing on hover. Here is my code:

```
  <nav class="fluid nav"><ul>
    <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="menu.html">menu</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">Pris Fix</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dinner</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wine List</a></li>
        </ul>
   </li>
    <li><a href="reviews.html">reviews </a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact.html">contact</a></li>
```

THE CSS:

```
.nav
{   display:block;
padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
color: #676027;
font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: small;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}
.nav ul li{
display:inline;
padding: 0 2em 0 2em;
letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}
.nav ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
text-transform:uppercase;
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #696229;
}

.nav ul li a:hover, .nav ul li a:active, .nav ul li a:focus
{color: #000;}

.nav ul li .subnav{display:none;}
.nav ul li .subnav li a{font-size: x-small;}
.nav ul li:hover ul .subnav{display:block; position:absolute;}
.nav ul li:hover ul .subnav a{display:block; width: 80px;}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `position:absolute;` needs positioning. Try getting rid of it to see it works at all before fussing with values

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of the code http://jsfiddle.net/T49ZW/ (including missing closing ul and nav tag, this way it is easier for folks to help you =]

Answer (score 0):

The position you can give on .nav , or you can see the references in here http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is this

```
.nav ul li:hover ul .subnav{display:block; position:absolute;}
.nav ul li:hover ul .subnav a{display:block; width: 80px;}
```

the `ul .subnav` should be attached to eachother or else you are searching for the child `.subnav` of the `ul`.

So change `ul .subnav` into `ul.subnav`. No space inbetween.